# How to generate many Kubernetes ResourceQuota with Helm Variables?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-helm

I have a OpenShift/Kubernetes new cluster and I need to create multiple ResourceQuota(s) and apply them to existing projects.

Every ResourceQuota should be applied to a given namespace and should contain a specific number of requests and limits.
I would like to generate all the needed ResourceQuota YAMs and deploy them by using Helm.

I created a new custom Helm Chart with the command

```
helm template resourcequota
```

and I see Helm creating the following files:

```
    .
..
.helmignore
Chart.yaml
charts
templates
values.yaml
```

I then wrote a `resourcequota.yaml` in the `templates` folder. I would like helm to fill the ResourceQuota specs for me:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.namespace }}-quota
  namespace: {{ .Values.namepace }}
spec:
  hard:
    cpu: {{ .Values.namespace.requests.cpu }}
    limits.cpu: {{ .Values.namespace.limits.cpu }}
    memory: {{ .Values.namespace.requests.memory }}
    limits.memory: {{ .Values.namespace.limits.cpu }}
```

The `values.yaml` file contains a first namespace name with sample values:

```
...
83 ...
84 namespace: "123-testnamespace"
85   requests:
86     cpu: "2"
87     memory: "1Gi"
88   limits:
89     cpu: "2"
90     memory: "1Gi"
```

I then asked Helm to locally generate a template with `helm template resourcequota` but it seems he doesn't know the namespace key (row 84):

`Error: cannot load values.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 84: did not find expected key`

What am I doing wrong ? I tried to write the `values.yaml` from scratch but it seems like I am missing out some helm fundamentals here.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

> it seems like I am missing out some helm fundamentals here

True, As mentioned in error there is an issue at line 84

```
84 namespace: "123-testnamespace"
85   requests:
86     cpu: "2"
87     memory: "1Gi"
88   limits:
89     cpu: "2"
90     memory: "1Gi"
```

basic YAML can not create an array of value and use it as key also.

You should have to use the values.yaml like

```
  namespacename : "123-testnamespace"
  namespace:
    requests:
      cpu: "2"
      memory: "1Gi"
    limits:
      cpu: "2"
      memory: "1Gi"
```

**YAML template**

Using change at **name** & **namespace** values in template

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.namespacename }}-quota
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespacename }}
spec:
  hard:
    cpu: {{ .Values.namespace.requests.cpu }}
    limits.cpu: {{ .Values.namespace.limits.cpu }}
    memory: {{ .Values.namespace.requests.memory }}
    limits.memory: {{ .Values.namespace.limits.cpu }}
```

Example of nested **YAML**

```
cartParams:
  - title: Test 1
    options:
      - Oh lala
      - oh lalalalala
  - title: Title test 2
    options:
      - oh lala
      - oh lala
      - oh lalala
      - oh lalalalalalalala
      - oh lalalalalalalalalala
```

Comment: Thank you Harsh for supporting. I created successfully the first ResourceQuota with your suggestion. It seems like anyway helm doesn't like a list of namespaces. Could you reformulate your last example of nested YAML with also an example of template using nested values ?

Comment: Hi Harsh, issue is not resolved. How to insert multiple namespaces in values.yaml file ?

Comment: that you are managing differently n ? you will be creating the multiple block in values.yaml or use loop with list of namespaces. Looks like that you have not mentioned in question above. you can use range

Comment: read more about loop: https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/#looping-with-the-range-action

Comment: @Luigi Sambolino, did you solve the problem with inserting multiple namespaces in values.yaml with the suggested loops?

Comment: Hi Ivan, I am trying to write an iterator which generates multiple objects by using some formulas found in the documentation linked by Harsh. I will update asap when finished, I am open to solutions if any.